# How to cross compile large projects?

Tags: linux, cross-compilation

Read through the posts on the website, and tried many scratchbox2/qemu attempts. I am beat when it comes to compiling large projects, that have many dependences. I found it easy to compile a single .c or .cpp file, but large projects that have ./configure seem to not work.

A few things I have tried:

1. Install Scratchbox2, Qemu, deboostrap an armfs, sb2-init, and try to use it to ./configure && make
2. distcc

I am totally stuck. Any suggestions on how to create an environment which allows me to use source code, and their utilities to compile RPI binaries?

Comment: buildroot is particularly good in case you want to build a minimal embedded system from scratch

Answer (score 2):

Ever tried QtCreator?  That makes use of CMake and takes all the hassle out of your hands when it comes to creating makefiles, since CMake creates them for you.

There's tutorials on how to set up a QtCreator project (C/C++) on the web.

I'm using QtCreator on Linux for a couple of months now for the FoxBoard (not done it yet for the Raspberry, but I would expect that's the same approach) and am very satisfied about how it works and performs.  I can even debug my FoxBoard without having to leave the QtCreator environment.  Works also fine for "large" projects.

The only thing you have to make yourself acquainted with, is the CMake syntax itself, but that's just a matter of reading about CMake on the CMake website itself.

Comment: The problem is compiling other peoples software, not really mine. They usually have huge autoconfig scripts, bootstraps, configures, and finally their make...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at one of these tools which can help you with these kind of things:
Buildroot http://buildroot.uclibc.org/
Nard SDK http://www.arbetsmyra.dyndns.org/nard/